# I am facing problem in running the backend of a github repository

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github, npm, npm-scripts

I hope you are doing great,
I am trying to cloning one of the Github repository,
here's the link to repo:
https://github.com/thevarunjain/job-portal-mern-stack

I've done everything according to my knowledge, I've run the MongoDB, install all the dependencies by npm I, frontend is running successfully but whenever I run the backend "npm run dev" am getting this error:

** ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/index.js

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. **

here's the script of package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/index.js"
  }
```

Please let me know how can I fix this issue, thanks!

Comment: Do you have node_modules folder in your backend folder?

Comment: yes I have node modules folder in the backend

Comment: i usually write `"dev": "nodemon src/index.js"` instead of `"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/index.js"`. You can try it

Comment: I've tried it already still I got the error